# Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to install dompdf using composer, I followed the instructions from [Installing DOMPDF with Composer](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/DOMPDF-and-Composer-Quick-start-guide#dompdf-06-family)

So far I've

- In composer.json

  ```
  ...
  "require": {
      ...
      "dompdf/dompdf": "~0.6.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
  ....
  ```
- run `composer update`
- in autoload.php already have `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`
- In vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php
  changed `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", true);` to `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", false);`
- My controller code

```

```
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;      
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;

require_once "vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";

class ArticleController extends BaseController {
  ...
  public function downloadPdf(){
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->output();
  }
}
```

- "post" route for ArticleController@downloadPdf

so now when I try to download pdf, if gives me error:

> exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with
>   message 'Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found'

have I missed any setup step or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue at dompdf github page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1003) helped me to solve this error

> The latest stable (0.6.1) does not support namespaces and so would not need the use statement in your code. The upcoming release (0.7.0) does include namespace support.

So, I just removed

```
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;      
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;
```

and used `new DOMPDF();` instead of `new Dompdf();` as with version 0.6.* namespace will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you want use the [dompdf 0.6 family](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/cf7d8a0a27270418850cc7d7ea532159e5eeb3eb). In the 0.6 version all the classes are in global space. But since your code is ready to the 0.7, change it to

```
"dompdf/dompdf": "~0.7"
```

and run `composer update`.

Comment: Updating the dompdf version would help, but on their github page it shows v0.6.2 as stable version, so I don't really want to update to 0.7, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @RHM, then remove `use Dompdf\Dompdf;`. Like I said, all the classes are in globalspace. `$dompdf = new \Dompdf();`

Comment: I tried that @Federico, but with version 0.6 I can't use Dompdf or \Dompdf, as namespace doesn't exists in it.

Answer (score 1):

Open file config.php

```
application/config/config.php
```

Then Change

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = "FALSE";
```

To

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = "vendor/autoload.php";
```